# Managing a nested resource in Jax-RS/Jersey that sometimes should behave as a non-nested resource

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs, nested-resources

I am developing simple APIs with Jax-RS Jersey. Let's say I am considering the domain of items sold by stores in some country.

My design includes these two calls :

- /webapi/items
- /webapi/store/1/items

Both of them should return a list of items, the first one should return all the items sold in that country, the second one should return only the items sold by store number 1.

I have of course two resources, an ItemResource which handles all the requests regarding items, and a StoreResource which handles all requests regarding stores.

```
@Path("items")
class ItemResource {

@GET
public List<Item> getAllItems(){
}
```

.

```
@Path("stores")
class StoreResource

@GET
@Path("/{storeId}/items")
public List<Item> getItemsSoldByStore(@PathParam("storeId") long storeId) {
}
```

What I would like to do is to pass the second request to the ItemResource, in order to avoid coupling between `StoreResource` and model class `Item` or database interfaces (like DAOs) specifically created to manage Items.
I know I can consider ItemResource like a sub-resource, or a nested resource of StoreResource, but the point is that this is not always true, since sometimes I would like to call ItemResource without passing a store id, to get all items (this is the case of the first request http://foo.com/webapi/items ). 
I'd like to keep the `@Path("items")` annotation on the `ItemResource` so it handles every request to /items endpoint.

What is the correct design in this situation? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't know if it's the best thing to do, but you can still put nothing in the class annotation(`@Path("/")` for example) and add `"/item"` and `"/stores..."` to your function annotations, but in this case all requests will be redirected to the same class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think this is a very common situation, so I was wondering if I am missing something important concerning the design. What about creating a non-nested resource with the annotation @Path("items") and a nested resource with annotation @Path("/")?

Comment: But in this case "http://foo.com/webapi/stores/...", wont be caught by your resource, since the root path is "items".

Answer (score 0):

You can create nested resource by returning a resource from your parent resource.

```
// Parent resource
@Path("stores")
class StoreResource {

  @GET
  @Path("/{storeId}/items")
  public List<Item> getItemsSoldByStore(@PathParam("storeId") long storeId) {
     return ItemResource(storeId);
  }
}

// nested resource

class ItemResource {

  @GET
  @Path("{storeId}")
  public List<Item> getAllItems(@PathParam("storeId")){
     // return your items
  }
}
```